# Let $R = \mathbb{Z} + x\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Find all the irreducibles in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $R = \mathbb{Z} + x\mathbb{Q}[x] \subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Find the irreducibles of $R$.
>
> Show that the irreducible elements in $R$ are $\pm p$ for prime integers $p$ and the irreducible polynomials $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ whose constant coefficient is $\pm 1$. Prove these irreducibles are prime in $R$.

The first part is pretty clear. ($\pm p$ for prime integers $p$), if $\alpha \in R$ s.t. $\deg(\alpha)=0$ then $\alpha$ is a constant polynomial thus in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $\alpha$ is a prime then it is irreducible.

Having trouble showing that for $p(x) \in R$ s.t. $\deg(p(x)) > 0$ with constant term $\pm 1$ are irreducible.

Comment: Do you mean $\subset \mathbb Q[x]$?

Comment: I don't think the statement is true. For example, $\pm p$ is irreducible but does not have constant term $\pm 1$. Or, $(1+x)(1+x)$ is a polynomial whose constant coefficient is $1$, so it is not irreducible (assuming that you can see that $1+x$ is not a unit).

Comment: @rogerl $(1+x)^2$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264077/irreducible-is-prime-in-the-ring-mathbbz-x-mathbbqx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's obvious that an irreducible polynomial $p\in\mathbb Q[x]$ with $p(0)=\pm 1$ remains so in $R$.

The question is to prove that these are the only irreducible elements of $R$ of degree $\ge 1$.

> Let $p\in R$ irreducible with $\deg p\ge1$.

If $k=|p(0)|>1$, then $p(x)=kq(x)$ with $q\in R$, so $p$ is reducible, a contradiction.
If $p(0)=0$, then $p(x)=xq(x)$ with $q\in\mathbb Q[x]$. Write $q(0)=\frac mn$, notice that $p(x)=(\frac 1nx)(nq(x))$ and $\frac 1nx,nq(x)\in R$, a contradiction.

Now suppose $p(0)=\pm1$, but $p$ is reducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Thus $p(x)=u(x)v(x)$ with $u,v\in\mathbb Q[x]$ with $\deg u,\, \deg v\ge1$. In particular, $u(0)v(0)=\pm1$, so we can assume $u(0)=v(0)=\pm1$ (why?). This shows that $p$ is reducible in $R$, a contradiction.

Comment: your answer is slightly confusing. can you explain $k = |p(x)| > 0$ then $p(x) = kq(x)$

Comment: @oliverjones Well, $k=|p(0)|>1$ (please read the answer carefully !). Then you can force $k$ as a common factor and write $p(x)=k\frac 1kp(x)$. Set $q(x)=\frac 1kp(x)$ and note that $q(0)=\frac 1kp(0)=1$.

Comment: are you using k is the absolute value of $p(0)$ or are you taking some sort of norm? you also say if $p(0)=0$, then ( then what?). What if $p(x)=x+5$ ? is that not irreducible?

Comment: $p(x)=x+5 \in R$,  $|p(0)|=|0+5|=5$ this is irreducible in $R$ and does not have constant $\pm 1$ so I am still not following

Comment: $x+5$ is *reducible* in $R$: write $x+5=5(1+\frac 15x)$ and notice that $5,1+\frac 15x\in R$ are non-invertible. (In fact, $R^\times=\{\pm1\}$. It's important to know the invertibles of a ring you want to study its arithmetics!)

Comment: Can you explain this part "Now suppose $p(0)=\pm1$, but $p$ is reducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Thus $p(x)=u(x)v(x)$ with $u,v\in\mathbb Q[x]$ with $\deg u,\, \deg v\ge1$. In particular, $u(0)v(0)=1$, so we can assume $u(0)=v(0)=1$ (why?). This shows that $p$ is reducible in $R$, a contradiction." 

Because the im not understading how this says an irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with constant $\pm 1$ is irreducible in $R$

Comment: No, this part doesn't prove what you say! In this part I've shown (by contradiction) that if $p$ is irreducible in $R$ and $p(0)=±1$ then $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$. (The converse, as I've pointed out in the first line of my answer, is trivial: if $p$ is reducible in $R$ then $p$ is clearly reducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$, don't you think?)

Comment: you said in that portion that $p$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ so I don't see the contradiction of it being reducible in $R$

Comment: Maybe you missed this part: "*Let $p\in R$ irreducible with $\deg p\ge1$.*"